# get file name and write it before every line of the same txt document?

Tags: regex, sorting, text, insert

what program can i use to get the filename of a txt document and write the name of the file before every line of the same document.
example:

file name : document1.txt

inside the document lines are like this:

```
1.-text text text
2.-text text text
3.-text
```

i want them to be automatically:

```
document1.txt 1.-text text text
document1.txt 2.-text text text
document1.txt 3.-text
```

i am doing this to sort the content of thousands of txt files, every line is listed with numbers, so that way if i merge them i don't lose order when i sort the content.
if i am able to put the name of the document and if i sort the merged content will be ok.

cause document1 can be in english language
but another document1 is in spanish language
but both are listed with the same number of lines.

i want to merged them in one document, but are more than 30 thousand txt
after merging all of them, i want the english and spanish version together.

```
document1.txt 1.-(english) text text text
document1.txt 1.-(spanish) text text text
document1.txt 2.-(english) text text text
document1.txt 2.-(spanish) text text text
document1.txt 3.-(english) text
document1.txt 3.-(spanish) text
```

in every line of the english documents i have look like this:

```
1.- <english> text ........
2.- <english> text .......
etc
```

and in every line of the spanish documents look like this:

```
1.- <spanish> text ........
2.- <spanish> text .......
etc
```

i don't know how to achieve this, please can you suggest something no too difficult?
i am not programmer, and i was wondering if there is a software to do this.

i just need to place the name of the file before every line of my documents.
something like a script.

thank you very much, i tried to explained with detailed my problem, but english is not my mother language. so i am sorry if any mistake.
greetings from mexico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a perl script that'll get the job done:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

foreach my $file (glob("*.txt"))
{
        my $newfile = $file;
        $newfile =~ s/\.txt$/_modified.txt/;
        open IN,"<$file";
        open OUT, ">>$newfile";
        while (<IN>) { print OUT $file . " " . $_ }
        close IN;
        close OUT;
}
```

It does what you described with .txt files in the same directory, and writes the result to *_modified.txt (so that your originals aren't destroyed)

Comment: thank you very much, i don't know perl, but i watched some videos. should i place the script in the same folder? do i have to change something in the script you gave?  , i will install perl.

Comment: Learning Perl, a.k.a. the Camel Book... more useful to me than any book i had to read in school :)
Plus it's an easy language to pick up, regardless of your background

Comment: and since you don't know perl, i'm guessing you're on a windows machine, in which case i can recommend the activeperl distribution by www.activestate.com

Comment: i downloaded i will follow instructions, variables of the system and all of that, should i place a .pl script on the same folder where all my documents are? and doble click on it, and that's it?

Comment: What i normally do on windows machines: Drop in the script as you said, open cmd, cd to the directory in question, and run `perl scriptname.pl`
Assuming activeperl installed correctly, perl will be a regognized command from your cmd prompt

Comment: omg it is working, really thank you very much, i am loving perl, i knew it was good, because i use regular expressions perl type, but scripting is another world.  really you saved my hours, haha i was getting crazy trying to make it manually , really thanks a lot.